# web audio in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-audio-api

i am trying to build a web app that visualises and and controls the source audio, it works brilliant in chrome, but completely breaks in firefox, it won't even play the audio. here is the code:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src='track.mp3';
audio.controls = true;
audio.loop = false;
audio.autoplay = false;


window.addEventListener("load", initPlayer, false);

function initPlayer(){
  $("#player").append(audio);

  context = new AudioContext();
  analyser = context.createAnalyser();
  canvas = document.getElementById("vis");;
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  source.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(context.destination);

}
```

the line that breaks everything is:

```
  source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
```

after adding this line the player just hangs at 0:00 in firefox. i have done my research and have come across CORS, but as far as i can understand this should be irrelevant as the file is kept on the same server.

Please help

Comment: When you say "breaks everything", does that mean that an error is thrown? If so, what's the error message?

Comment: No error is thrown at all, it even sees the file, it just won't play the sound and sits at 0:00 when play is clicked

Answer (score 1):

You have to serve the audio correctly with a server so that MIME types are set, so run it from localhost rather than `file:///..../track.mp3`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you go into more detail how to implement that please?

Comment: Depends on your server, a general MAMP/LAMP/WAMP set up should probably do this.

Answer (score 0):

We used to have a bug in Firefox where MediaElementSourceNode did not work properly in some case. It's now fixed (I believe the fix is in Aurora and Nightly, at the time of writing).

Sorry about that.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, i have tried both, a nightly and aurora, they both refuse to play anything.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid I will need a minimal test case to investigate that,then. Could you provide a web page that show what does not work in Firefox and works in Chrome?